# Accessing a JTextArea in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea in (multiple) JScrollPane in a JTabbedPane.

I need to access the JTextArea.  If I didn't have the JScrollPane, I could do:

```
JTextArea c = (JTextArea)jTabbedPane1.getComponentAt(i);
```

How would I get it when in a JScrollPane?

Cheers,
Gazler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line looks complex, but I *THINK* this would do it.

```
JTextArea c = (JTextArea) (((JViewportView) (((JScrollPane) jTabbedPane1.getComponentAt(i)).getViewport()))).getView();
```

But I think it would be more interesting to store your `TextArea`'s in an `ArrayList`.
So you can do this:

```
List<JTextArea> listAreas = new ArrayList<JTextArea>();

...
JTextArea c = listAreas.get(i);
```

Create a new one is something like this:

```
JTextArea c = new JTextArea();
jTabbedPane1.addTab("Title", new JScrollPane(c));
listAreas.add(c);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you'll get into a mess of references over there ( at least that's what have happened to me in the past ) .

I would suggest you to have a middle object in charge of those dependencies for you and to move the "business" methods there.

So instead of adding components and losing the references ( or worst, duplicating the references all over the place ) you can use this object which will have the reference:

```
class AppMediator {
     private JTextArea area;
     private JTabbetPane pane;

     // etc. 

     public void doSomethingWithText() {
          this.area.getText(); // etc 
     }
 }
```

See the [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) design pattern. The focus is to move all the "view" objects from where they are ( usually as references in subclasses ) to a common intermediate object.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the AppMediator approach but you could also do

```
scrollPane.getViewport().getView()
```