# Java issue. Trying to show a JScrollPane in a JOptionPane

Tags: java

Well, as the title says I'm trying to show a JScrollPane in my JOptionPane menu, but it doesn't work. I think the reason is that what it's actually showing is the JScrollPane direction in memory, not the JScrollPane's content itself. This is what's shown (the JScrollPane should appear after "Libros:"):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pAHQsBI.png]

**The menu:**

```
        int iOpcion = EntradaGraficaDatos.pedirEntero(
                "Introduzca la acción a realizar:" 
        + "\n"
        + "\n    1. Añadir libro "
        + "\n    2. Añadir revista " 
        + "\n    3. Borrar libro "
        + "\n    4. Borrar revista " 
        + "\n    5. Mostrar libros "
        + "\n    6. Mostrar revistas "
        + "\n    7. Mostrar todas las publicaciones"
        + "\n    8. Prestar libro" 
        + "\n    9. Devolver libro"
        + "\n    10. Salir"
        + "\n"
        + "\n"
        + "                        MI BIBLIOTECA    "
        + "\n"
        + "Libros: \n" 
        + devuelveDatosEnTabla(miBiblioteca.getMisLibros())
        + "\n"
        + "Revistas: \n"
        + recogerDatos(miBiblioteca.getMisRevistas())
        + "\n"
        , "Menú", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

**The method returning the SCrollPane:**

```
// Método que devuelve un JScrollPane (tabla) que contiene las publicaciones del array de Publicaciones recibido
public JScrollPane devuelveDatosEnTabla(Publicacion[] publicacion) {
        Object [][] cuerpoTabla = new Object [publicacion.length][6];
        Object [] titulosColumnas = {"Tipo", "Código", "Título", "Año publicación", "Número", "Prestado"};
        for (int i = 0; i<publicacion.length; i++){
            if (publicacion[i] instanceof Libro && publicacion[i] !=null){
                cuerpoTabla[i][0] = "Libro";
                cuerpoTabla[i][1] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getCodigo());
                cuerpoTabla[i][2] = publicacion[i].getTitulo();
                cuerpoTabla[i][3] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getAño());
                cuerpoTabla[i][4] = "";
                cuerpoTabla[i][5] = Boolean.toString(((Libro) publicacion[i]).getPrestado());
            }
            if (publicacion[i] instanceof Revista && publicacion[i] !=null){
                cuerpoTabla[i][0] = "Revista";
                cuerpoTabla[i][1] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getCodigo());
                cuerpoTabla[i][2] = publicacion[i].getTitulo();
                cuerpoTabla[i][3] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getAño());
                cuerpoTabla[i][4] = Integer.toString(((Revista)publicacion[i]).getNumero());
                cuerpoTabla[i][5] = "";
            }   
        }
        JTable tabla = new JTable(cuerpoTabla, titulosColumnas);
        tabla.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabla);
        return scroll;
}
```

**And the whole App's code, doesn't let me put the imports and package don't know why :/**

public class Aplicacion {

```
// Variable de clase
private Biblioteca miBiblioteca;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Aplicacion();
    System.exit(0);
}

private Aplicacion() {
    jInit();
}

public void jInit() {

    miBiblioteca = new Biblioteca(EntradaGraficaDatos.pedirEntero(
            "Introduzca el número de publicaciones de la biblioteca",
            "Capacidad", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE));
    boolean salir = false;

    // -------------------------------------------------------MENU----------------------------------------------------------
    do {

        int iOpcion = EntradaGraficaDatos.pedirEntero(
                "Introduzca la acción a realizar:" 
        + "\n"
        + "\n    1. Añadir libro "
        + "\n    2. Añadir revista " 
        + "\n    3. Borrar libro "
        + "\n    4. Borrar revista " 
        + "\n    5. Mostrar libros "
        + "\n    6. Mostrar revistas "
        + "\n    7. Mostrar todas las publicaciones"
        + "\n    8. Prestar libro" 
        + "\n    9. Devolver libro"
        + "\n    10. Salir"
        + "\n"
        + "\n"
        + "                        MI BIBLIOTECA    "
        + "\n"
        + "Libros: \n" 
        + devuelveDatosEnTabla(miBiblioteca.getMisLibros())
        + "\n"
        + "Revistas: \n"
        + recogerDatos(miBiblioteca.getMisRevistas())
        + "\n"
        , "Menú", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        switch (iOpcion) {
        case 1:
            crearAñadirLibro();
            break;
        case 2:
            crearAñadirRevista();
            break;
        case 3:
            borrarLibro();
            break;
        case 4:
            borrarRevista();
            break;
        case 5:
            visualizarDatosTabla(miBiblioteca.getMisLibros());
            break;
        case 6:
            visualizarDatosTabla(miBiblioteca.getMisRevistas());
            break;
        case 7:
            visualizarDatosTabla(miBiblioteca.getMisPublicaciones());
            break;
        case 8:
            prestarLibro();
            break;
        case 9:
            devolverLibro();
            break;
        case 10:
            salir = true;
            break;
        }
    } while (!salir);

}

//---------------------------------------------METODOS---------------------------------------------------------------


// Método para crear los libros
private void crearAñadirLibro() {
    if (!miBiblioteca.bibliotecaLlena()) {
        Publicacion publicacion = crearPublicacion();
        Libro libro = new Libro(publicacion.getCodigo(),
                publicacion.getTitulo(), publicacion.getAño());
        miBiblioteca.añadirLibros(libro);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El libro ha sido añadido con éxito", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La biblioteca está llena", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);}
}

// Método para crear y añadir las revistas
private void crearAñadirRevista() {
    if (!miBiblioteca.bibliotecaLlena()) {
        Publicacion publicacion = crearPublicacion();
        int elNumero = EntradaGraficaDatos.pedirEntero("Número de la revista");
        Revista revista = new Revista(publicacion.getCodigo(),
                publicacion.getTitulo(), publicacion.getAño(), elNumero);
        miBiblioteca.añadirRevista(revista);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La revista ha sido añadida con éxito", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La biblioteca está llena", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);}
}

// Método para crear una publicacion
public Publicacion crearPublicacion() {
    int elCodigo;
    String elTitulo;
    int elAño;
    elCodigo = EntradaGraficaDatos.pedirEntero("Escribe el código");
    elTitulo = pedirDatos("Escribe el título");
    elAño = EntradaGraficaDatos.pedirEntero("Escribe el año");
    Publicacion publicacion = new Publicacion(elCodigo, elTitulo, elAño);
    return publicacion;
}

// Borra el libro cuyo nombre diga el usuario
public void borrarLibro(){
    Libro [] arrayLibros = miBiblioteca.getMisLibros();
    String libroABorrar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduzca el título del libro a borrar", "Borrar", 
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    boolean borrado = false;
    for (int i = 0; !borrado && i<arrayLibros.length; i++){
            if (libroABorrar.equals(arrayLibros[i].getTitulo())){
                miBiblioteca.borrarLibro(libroABorrar);
                borrado = true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El libro " + libroABorrar + " ha sido borrado con éxito", "", 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
    if (borrado == false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe un libro con ese título", "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}

// Borra la revista cuyo nombre diga el usuario
public void borrarRevista(){
    Revista [] arrayRevistas = miBiblioteca.getMisRevistas();
    String revistaABorrar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduzca el título de la revista a borrar", "Borrar", 
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    boolean borrado = false;
    for (int i = 0; !borrado && i<arrayRevistas.length; i++){
            if (revistaABorrar.equals(arrayRevistas[i].getTitulo())){
                miBiblioteca.borrarLibro(revistaABorrar);
                borrado = true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La revista " + revistaABorrar + " ha sido borrada con éxito", "", 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
    if (borrado == false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe un libro con ese título", "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}

// Método para prestar un libro
public void prestarLibro() {
    if (miBiblioteca.hayLibros()){
    int codigoPrestar = EntradaGraficaDatos
            .pedirEntero("Código del libro a prestar");
    int indice = miBiblioteca.buscarLibroCodigo(codigoPrestar);
    if (indice != -1) {
        (miBiblioteca.getMisLibros()[indice]).prestar();
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "No hay ningún libro con ese código");
    }
    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay libros en la biblioteca", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);}
}

public void devolverLibro() {
    if (miBiblioteca.hayLibros()){
    int codigoPrestar = EntradaGraficaDatos
            .pedirEntero("Código del libro a prestar");
    int indice = miBiblioteca.buscarLibroCodigo(codigoPrestar);
    if (indice != -1) {
        (miBiblioteca.getMisLibros()[indice]).devolver();
    }else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "No hay ningún libro con ese código");
    }
    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay libros en la biblioteca", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);}
}

// Método para visualizar los datos en un cuadro de texto
public void visualizarDatos(Publicacion[] publicacion) {
    if (miBiblioteca.hayLibrosORevistas()){
    String cadena = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < publicacion.length; i++) {
        if (publicacion[i] != null){
        cadena += publicacion[i].toString() + "\n";
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cadena, "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La biblioteca está vacía", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);}
}

// Método para visualizar los datos en una tabla
public void visualizarDatosTabla(Publicacion[] publicacion) {
    if (miBiblioteca.hayLibrosORevistas()){
        Object [][] cuerpoTabla = new Object [publicacion.length][6];
        Object [] titulosColumnas = {"Tipo", "Código", "Título", "Año publicación", "Número", "Prestado"};
        for (int i = 0; i<publicacion.length; i++){
            if (publicacion[i] instanceof Libro && publicacion[i] !=null){
                cuerpoTabla[i][0] = "Libro";
                cuerpoTabla[i][1] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getCodigo());
                cuerpoTabla[i][2] = publicacion[i].getTitulo();
                cuerpoTabla[i][3] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getAño());
                cuerpoTabla[i][4] = "";
                cuerpoTabla[i][5] = Boolean.toString(((Libro) publicacion[i]).getPrestado());
            }
            if (publicacion[i] instanceof Revista && publicacion[i] !=null){
                cuerpoTabla[i][0] = "Revista";
                cuerpoTabla[i][1] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getCodigo());
                cuerpoTabla[i][2] = publicacion[i].getTitulo();
                cuerpoTabla[i][3] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getAño());
                cuerpoTabla[i][4] = Integer.toString(((Revista)publicacion[i]).getNumero());
                cuerpoTabla[i][5] = "";
            }   
        }
        JTable tabla = new JTable(cuerpoTabla, titulosColumnas);
        tabla.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabla);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scroll, "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La biblioteca está vacía", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);}
}

// Método que devuelve un JScrollPane (tabla) que contiene las publicaciones del array de Publicaciones recibido
public JScrollPane devuelveDatosEnTabla(Publicacion[] publicacion) {
        Object [][] cuerpoTabla = new Object [publicacion.length][6];
        Object [] titulosColumnas = {"Tipo", "Código", "Título", "Año publicación", "Número", "Prestado"};
        for (int i = 0; i<publicacion.length; i++){
            if (publicacion[i] instanceof Libro && publicacion[i] !=null){
                cuerpoTabla[i][0] = "Libro";
                cuerpoTabla[i][1] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getCodigo());
                cuerpoTabla[i][2] = publicacion[i].getTitulo();
                cuerpoTabla[i][3] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getAño());
                cuerpoTabla[i][4] = "";
                cuerpoTabla[i][5] = Boolean.toString(((Libro) publicacion[i]).getPrestado());
            }
            if (publicacion[i] instanceof Revista && publicacion[i] !=null){
                cuerpoTabla[i][0] = "Revista";
                cuerpoTabla[i][1] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getCodigo());
                cuerpoTabla[i][2] = publicacion[i].getTitulo();
                cuerpoTabla[i][3] = Integer.toString(publicacion[i].getAño());
                cuerpoTabla[i][4] = Integer.toString(((Revista)publicacion[i]).getNumero());
                cuerpoTabla[i][5] = "";
            }   
        }
        JTable tabla = new JTable(cuerpoTabla, titulosColumnas);
        tabla.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabla);
        return scroll;
}

// Método que devuelve en un String los datos de los objetos de tipo Publicacion de un array que recibe
public String recogerDatos(Publicacion [] publicacion){
    String cadena = ""; 
    for (int i = 0; i < publicacion.length; i++) {
        cadena += publicacion[i].toString() + "\n";
    }
    return cadena;
}

/* Pedir datos */
public static String pedirDatos(String mensaje) {
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mensaje);
}
```

}

thanks in advance!!

Comment: post codes not images

Comment: You are allowed to use internet while doing your exam ? :O

Comment: lol obviously not, it's just a mock exam. The real one is on Tuesday!

Comment: You should post the entire code so we can reproduce, there is a lot of missing code in your example.

Comment: Jean-François do you mean the whole App? not the data classes right? Ok, just a sec

Comment: Post enought so we can reproduce, but get rid of all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not easy for us to debug, please read [how to create a mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting another question.

---

Here a minimal example of how you can achieve adding a `JScrollPane` to a `JOptionPane`

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("default text");
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane, "some text", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
```

as simple as that.

---

**Edit :** You actually got to display the `JScrollPane` right. The problem is that the given text concatenate a `JScrollPane` which by default will call the `toString` and display the memory address.

```
int iOpcion = EntradaGraficaDatos.pedirEntero(
            "Introduzca la acción a realizar:" 
    + "\n"
    + "\n    1. Añadir libro "
    + "\n    2. Añadir revista " 
    + "\n    3. Borrar libro "
    + "\n    4. Borrar revista " 
    + "\n    5. Mostrar libros "
    + "\n    6. Mostrar revistas "
    + "\n    7. Mostrar todas las publicaciones"
    + "\n    8. Prestar libro" 
    + "\n    9. Devolver libro"
    + "\n    10. Salir"
    + "\n"
    + "\n"
    + "                        MI BIBLIOTECA    "
    + "\n"
    + "Libros: \n" 
    + devuelveDatosEnTabla(miBiblioteca.getMisLibros())//This method return a scroll pane, the toString method will be called and the memory address will be displayed.
    + "\n"
    + "Revistas: \n"
    + recogerDatos(miBiblioteca.getMisRevistas())
    + "\n"
    , "Menú", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

You did it correct here

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabla);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scroll, "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: ahh so that's it! if I concatenate a JScrollPane to a String it will call toString() and display the memory address. The question is... Is it possible to avoid the toString() call and just concatenate a JScrollPane to a String to be displayed in the same JOptionPane window? Thanks btw

Comment: @ArturAlvaro No, it is impossible as the scroll pane is an object. However, you can retrieve it text content by retrieving the text area associated to it and then call the `getText` method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834382/accessing-a-jtextarea-in-a-jscrollpane

Comment: but the thing is that showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int messageType) accepts both Strings and JScrollPanes in "message" (it actually works and shows the table if I don't concatenate it to a String), but the issue comes when I try to put both String and JScrollPane displaying at the same time :S

Comment: That's because when you concatenate the scroll pane to a string object, it will try to convert the scroll pane to a string by calling the default tostring method. If you want to display the content of the pane, you have no other choice than retrieving the text area and call the getText method.

Comment: Sorry but I have no knowledge regarding neither text areas nor the getText method. You basically mean to export the JScrollPane's info to a String? Thanks again